# Select consecutive rows once it fulfills a particular condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Select the consecutive rows once it fulfills the condition. Example :

```
dfA : 
style  day  stock
pants  mon   0
pants  tue   2
pants  wed   1
pants  thu   0
pants  fri   1
pants  sat   0
shirt  sat   1
shirt  thu   2
shirt  mon   0
shirt  tue   0
shirt  wed   2
shirt  fri   0
```

select the consecutive rows after ordering of the days and once the stock becomes > 0

```
expected output :
pants  tue   2
pants  wed   1
pants  thu   0
pants  fri   1
pants  sat   0
shirt  sat   1
shirt  thu   0
shirt  wed   2
shirt  fri   0
```

So here in pants once the stock reached 2 on tuesday we select all the days after that, and in shirt once the stock reached 2 on wednesday we selected all the days after that.
I tried grouping by and > 0 conditions but didn't get the expected results, any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: please add the expected output

Comment: Yea the resulting dataframe was the expected output

Comment: How do you do the "ordering of the days"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, which may not be the most elegant but it has the advantage of being rather clear.

Here I introduce intermediate columns with the day id (in the correct week order!) and with the first day with stock for each style. Then you just need to compare these two columns.

```
week = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"]
fun = lambda x: week.index(x)
a["day_id"] = a["day"].map(fun)   # column with day id
first_day = a[a["stock"] > 0].groupby("style")["day_id"].min()   # select lines with stock>0 and find first day per style
a["first_day"] = a["style"].map(first_day)   # column with first day with stock per style (very redundant)
result = a[a["day_id"] >= a["first_day"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach applying grouping.
Create temporary dict to hold the resulting grouped dfs:

```
dict_temp = {key: None for key in df["style"].unique()}
```

Get the remaining rows after the condition is met:

```
for key in dict_temp:
    # get the index of first True of condition (here ==2)
    index_fist_true = np.where(df.groupby("style").get_group(key)["stock"]==2)[0][0]
    # save the rest of grouped dataframe in dict_temp
    dict_temp[key] = df.groupby("style").get_group(key).reset_index()[index_fist_true+1:]
```

Concat the values of dict_temp and transform it:

```
pd.concat(dict_temp.values()).drop("index", axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```